# Spring JDBC batch update query without prepared statements

Tags: java, sql, spring, performance, jdbc

I have a legacy code where I am not allowed to use prepared statements. 
Its using Spring JDBC and update query. The requirement is to update 100,000 rows.
I have a Map which has row number and the value that needs to be updated in specific column.

Here is my current code:

```
            for(String seq: recordIdMap.keySet()){

            Object[] parameters = new Object[2];
            parameters[0] = seq;
            parameters[1] = recordIdMap.get(seq); 
//<setting the params in query using manual string replace- earlier query has (1) (2) ... in query . This is not prepared statement>
                getJdbcTemplate().update(query);
        }
```

I need to change this to execute as a batch so that after the for loop i can execute it in a single DB hit.

What is the best way to use spring JDBC batch update for this requirement?

Comment: Why are you not allowed to use prepared statements? Running a 100k individual updates will be much slower than running the same prepared statement 100k times. Also, a batch size of 100k seems a bit too much; splitting the total into batches of 500/1000 rows might be a better idea.

Comment: The query is already written by someone else and I am not supposed to update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would read everything and convert it into a list of object array and then run batchUpdate.

```
List<Object[]> params = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
for(Entry<String,String> entry : recordIdMap.entrySet())
    params.add(new Object[] {entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()});

getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(query, params);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: do i need to update the query for this requirement, i don't have access to query string as it is read from external module.

Comment: as long as the query has the '?' place holder it should be fine... eg. update tbContact set firstname = ?, lastname  =?

Comment: Thanks, let me check if i can make it work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If the query has bind parameters (`?` or `:param` placeholders), then by definition, it's a prepared statement, which OP was not allowed to use.